# When should I use susy-media instead of susy-breakpoint

Tags: susy-sass, susy

Is there any use-case for [susy-media](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/toolkit/#susy-media) mixin? [Susy-breakpoint](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/toolkit/#susy-breakpoint) seems to provide same functionality if used without *layout* parameter. If so, susy-media seems useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Susy-media provides all the media-query logic used by susy-breakpoint — and serves as a built-in replacement for something like the Breakpoint plugin. If you want to use named media-queries without changing the grid, or if you just like the syntax, it's available — but you are right that it does nothing special for Susy.

Comment: So would it be right to say that susy-media is a service mixin to be used by susy-breakpoint? Аnd there is no reason to use susy-media instead of susy-breakpoint in any cases as you can achieve all the same with susy-breakpoint as with susy-media plus the layout changes?

Comment: Yeah, that's fair. Anything you might do with susy-media you can do with susy-breakpoint.